# Is there a way to delete a file in Azure blob storage from trigger delete in SQL Server Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs

I have an ASP.NET MVC application where the files are uploaded to Azure blob storage and the generated filenames are saved in a table in a SQL Server database in Azure. I want to delete the file directly in the database and I want the delete trigger to be able to delete the files in the Azure blob storage.

Maybe PowerShell would work but seems that is not supported by SQL Server Azure

> Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.dbo.xp_cmdshell' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at Azure Functions? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/

Comment: I already have an App Service, do I have to pay extra for that? The "Timer-based processing" function could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-transact-sql-information) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/general-extended-stored-procedures-transact-sql), CLR Stored procs, Query Notifications, Extended stored procs are all not available on Azure sql.

So I think we couldn’t directly delete the blob by using the sql server trigger.

One way:
You could use queue trigger in azure webjob to delete the sql record and blob file.

You could add a message(Include the blob file name) to the queue in your web application or using azure storage explorer.

Then in the webjob, you could write code to delete the blob file and sql record according to this queue message.

More details about how to use queue trigger in azure webjob, you could refer to below article:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to

Another way:

You could enable change tracking on the specific table so that you could use scheduled webjob discovers the latest changes (i.e. delete) to the table and according to the record to delete the file in the blob.

More details you could refer to below query and article:

1.Enable change tracking:

```
ALTER DATABASE yourdatabase  
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON  
(CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON)  

ALTER TABLE YourBolbTable
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING  
WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON)
```

2.Select the changed records:

```
SELECT
*
FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES YourBlobTable, 0) AS ChTbl;
```

Result:
[image]

Notice: I suggest you could use blob name as primary key since if you delete the record the change tracking table just record the primary key.

More details about how to use change tracking table, you could refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/track-data-changes-sql-server).

Then you could use [timertrigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger) or [scheduled webJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs#a-namecreatecontinuousacreate-a-continuously-running-webjob) ] to get the table changed records every minutes.

At last, you could delete the blob according to this record in webjob by using azure storage SDK.

Comment: You helped me out with the second option. Because I have several tables where I save the files, instead of enabling change tracking I've created a single table to store all the deleted files from all tables with the trigger delete in each one. Then the schedule webjob just have to check if that table has rows and proceed to delete the file and row. Thanks for your detailed answer.